# Apache 2.4 gives Forbidden Files deny server access

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

Ok, I have a weird thing going on -

I have LAMP setup with a pseudo virtual hosting where for each user a system user is created and all his files are owned by the user.

So here is the flow -> user signs up using the web service -> a new system user is created (Say user1) -> A new group is created (user1 with user1 and www-data as memebers) -> all the files the user uploads are owned by user1:user1 with permissions - Files: 0770 and Folders: 0771

Now my issue is when I try to open (example.com/UserFolder/abc.html), apache gives a "Forbidden : File permissions deny server access).

If I restart/reload apache, it starts working fine. What is going on here? Why do I need to restart apache for it to be able to recognize the new user?